# FutureBuilder doesn't return widget

Tags: android, flutter

I have been trying to print base64 encoded image string on my screen after taking a snap. The following is the code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
  }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);



    final String title;

   @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    File _image;







     Future<String> getb64Image() async {
        List<int> imageBytes= await _image.readAsBytes();
        String b64image= base64Encode(imageBytes);
        print('In future func: $b64image\n');
         return b64image;
     }

     void clickPic() async {
       var image= await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
       setState(() {
         _image=image;
       });
   }

  Widget getImage(){
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getb64Image(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        print('In snapshot : ${snapshot.data}');
        return new Text(snapshot.data);
      }
      else{
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
    else{
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(

    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(

    child: Column(

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[



        Center(
          child: _image!=null?getImage():Container(child: Text(
            'Click below to take a snap',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),),
        ),



        RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: clickPic,
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),

            label:Text('click me to take a snap'),

        )

      ],
    ),
  ),

);
 }
 }
```

My flutter version s 1.2.1 and I am using Android Studio 3.3. The problem is while the app runs fine till taking the snap, when trying to get the b64 converted image string onto the screen, the futurebuilder doesn't build anything. The app gets stuck without even the animation of CircularProgressIndicator and stops suddenly. The console doesn't print any errors except 'Application finished' or 'Lost connection to device'. The debug lines I put in FutureBuilder and b64Image method work but the only problem is FutureBuilder crashing without printing the string. Please note that I am running the app on android emulator.

This is the link to sample run of the code in emulator:https://youtu.be/291sQtow3Q4

The following is the console log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
I/.flutter_pylen(12574): Background young concurrent copying GC freed      3846(621KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 84% free, 1103KB/7247KB, paused 214us total 119.231ms
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/Choreographer(12574): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb612b40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdb608da0)
I/OpenGLRenderer(12574): Davey! duration=1686ms; Flags=1,    IntendedVsync=3188489793352, Vsync=3190023126624,   OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=3190028534473, AnimationStart=3190028585003, PerformTraversalsStart=3190028607203, DrawStart=3190037234683, SyncQueued=3190038151683, SyncStart=3190052614713, IssueDrawCommandsStart=3190052729313, SwapBuffers=3190081882083,  FrameCompleted=3190190896713, DequeueBufferDuration=59694000,  QueueBufferDuration=238000, 
 D/        (12574): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd68cab80, tid 12598
 D/        (12574): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 GL_OES_vertex_array_object  GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec6e9660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd67b6d40)
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb612b40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdb608da0)
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglCreateContext: 0xec6e9840: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec6e9840: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd67b6c20)
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb612b40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdb608da0)
 D/EGL_emulation(12574): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec6e9840: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd67b6d40)
 I/flutter (12574): In future func: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD 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
I/flutter (12574): In snapshot : 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
 Application finished.
```

The issue I have is there is no error being shown. So, I am unable to understand what the problem is.Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You are trying to show a text widget containing a string with presumably several thousand characters. This probably isn't useful and might cause something to run out of memory. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Is this really what you want to do? Yes, kinda. My main aim of app is to send the encoded image to server which performs some classification task and returns a json. I was trying to print the encoded image string just to check if FutureBuilder is working or not. As of now, I haven't completed my server code. So, I can't check my actual case. Although, even the text from server would be of length greater than the current string that I am trying to print. Is there any other way to handle this situation?

Comment: So why not print something reasonable, like: `Text('base 64 is available with length $(snapshot.data.length)')`

Comment: While that worked, when I will have to populate the text widget with larger data, which I will, it won't work. I tried using RichText and TextSpan. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your android process is getting killed as Dart VM is taking too much time to render your "fat" Text data.

You should be seeing logs like below :

```
03-17 20:03:55.922   712   712 I Zygote  : Process 12250 exited due to signal (9)
```

and

```
I/Choreographer(20099): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

search for `exited due to signal` for your process in android logcat.

Basically `Text widget could not handle string with millions of characters`
It's probably trying to render too much text on the main thread in one shot.

While there could be a graceful developer message in this scenario from flutter, currently there isn't any. 
Raised an issue for the same : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29510

Comment: I am unabe to find the logcat tab for android. But the log messages for app are printed in the 'run' tab. Although 'exited due to signal' isn't mentioned, there is a log that says application may be doing too much work on main thread.